# NUMBA - How to generate random numbers in @guvectorize with "cuda" target?

Tags: numba

In this (dumb) example I am trying to compute pi by counting the number of randomly chosen points in (0, 1) x (0, 1) that fall into the unit circle.

```
@guvectorize(['void(float64[:], int32, float64[:])'], '(n),()->(n)', target='cuda')
def guvec_compute_pi(arr, iters, res):
    n = arr.shape[0]
    for t in range(n):
        inside = 0
        for i in range(iters):
            x = np.random.random()
            y = np.random.random()
            if x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= 1.0:
               inside += 1
        res[t] = 4.0 * inside / iters
```

This exception popped out during compilation:

```
numba.errors.UntypedAttributeError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'random' of type Module(<module 'numpy.random' from '...'>)
File "scratch.py", line 34
[1] During: typing of get attribute at /.../scratch.py (34)
```

I naively thought using the RNGs described [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/random.html) would solve the problem. My modified code looked like:

```
@guvectorize(['void(float64[:], int32, float64[:])'], '(n),()->(n)', target='cuda')
def guvec_compute_pi(arr, iters, res):
    n = arr.shape[0]
    rng = create_xoroshiro128p_states(n, seed=1)
    for t in range(n):
        inside = 0
        for i in range(iters):
            x = xoroshiro128p_uniform_float64(rng, t)
            y = xoroshiro128p_uniform_float64(rng, t)
            if x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= 1.0:
                inside += 1
        res[t] = 4.0 * inside / iters
```

However a similar error would pop out:

```
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'create_xoroshiro128p_states': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
File "scratch.py", line 28
```

When I tried changing to `target='parallel'` the original code that uses `numpy.random.random` works fine whether `nopython=True` or not. What has caused the problem with `target='cuda'` and is there a way to get random numbers in a `@guvectorize`-d block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function create_xoroshiro128p_states is intended to be run on the CPU as shown in this example from the Numba documentation, repeated below:

```
from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import

from numba import cuda
from numba.cuda.random import create_xoroshiro128p_states, 
xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32
import numpy as np

@cuda.jit
def compute_pi(rng_states, iterations, out):
    """Find the maximum value in values and store in result[0]"""
    thread_id = cuda.grid(1)

    # Compute pi by drawing random (x, y) points and finding what
    # fraction lie inside a unit circle
    inside = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        x = xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32(rng_states, thread_id)
        y = xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32(rng_states, thread_id)
        if x**2 + y**2 <= 1.0:
            inside += 1

    out[thread_id] = 4.0 * inside / iterations

threads_per_block = 64
blocks = 24
rng_states = create_xoroshiro128p_states(threads_per_block * blocks, seed=1)
out = np.zeros(threads_per_block * blocks, dtype=np.float32)

compute_pi[blocks, threads_per_block](rng_states, 10000, out)
print('pi:', out.mean())
```

It generates an array of random initialization data which keeps random number generation on the GPU independent across threads.  That data ends up on the device side, which is slightly confusing.  But it allows you to just pass in the random state data to your GPU kernels.

Comment: Is this the same thing: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/random.html ?